Specific fractions
What is the correct wording of the following fractions:
1/21 Is it "one-twenty-first" or rather "one-twenty-oneth"?
1/22 Is it "one-twenty-second" or "one-twenty-twoth"?
1/23 "one-twenty-third", I guess?
Similarly for denominators greater than one-hundred:
1/101 "one-one-hundred-first" or "one-one-hundred-oneth"?
etc.

This question is similar to: How to pronounce fractions with denominators larger than 20 where the last digit of the denominator is 1 or 2? eg 4/31. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Peter Shor''s answer includes: '... fractions with denominators ending with 1, 2, 3, as in twenty-firsts, twenty-seconds, twenty-thirds....

For confirmation, here is a definition from Merriam-Webster, one of the canonical American dictionaries.' M-W carries the example 'one twenty-first of the total'. And Wiktionary {here} has 'hundred-and-oneth', but 'hundred-and-first' [Wiktionary} is more common.

I mean seriously, did you look up twoth in a dictionary?

for all of the fractions you listed, it would be the first option. always ending with words like 'first' 'second' 'third'

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
